# How to playback audio data with several audio cards simultaneously using LWJGL (openal)?

Tags: java, audio, lwjgl, openal

I need to play audio data with several audio cards simultaneously. To begin with I don't know how change audio device with method:

```
AL.create("DirectSound3D", 44100, 15, false);
```

for use with another audio card in PC.